# To check for duplicate names in a name value field

Tags: servicenow

We have a name value field , and its not accepting duplicate names .However in integration , its creating record using the duplicate names .How do we validate this to ignore duplicate names in the request

Comment: Share your array.

Comment: There are never duplicate keys in an array.

Comment: Add "use strict"; to the top of your file. Which will throws a syntax error.

Comment: @JonasW. In an empty array, there's a duplicate for every key. :-O

Comment: Below is my array @AnkitAgarwal  {"Speed": "1200","Speed": "4","Bandwidth": "100"}

Comment: @DivyaG that is not a array. Edit your question and add the array there.

Answer (score 0):

Use array filter to the removed duplicate values

```js
const array =  ["test", "test1", "test2", "test", "test", "test1", "test", "test2", "test"];


var uniqueArray = array.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
})

console.log(uniqueArray);
```